# C# WPF Переопределение параметра в стиле

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, style, триггер

Есть стиль для кнопки:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>

                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"/>
                    <Label x:Name="buttonCaption" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonSurface" Property="Fill" Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="buttonCaption" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Есть окно где объявляется кнопка:

```
...
<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundButtonStyle}" Background="Blue"Foreground="Black" Content="POPO" />
...
```

Свойства Background, Foreground и Content у кнопки переопределяются через TemplateBinding.

**Вопрос** - Как дать возможность аналогично переопределять свойства в тригере? (На данный момент это "White" и "Red")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
  <Setter TargetName="buttonSurface" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
  <Setter TargetName="buttonCaption" Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}" />
</Trigger>
```

---

Создаем `UserControl` и наследуемся от `Button`, чтобы сохранить весь функционал стандартной кнопки. Создаем свойство зависимости в котором будет хранится цвет:

```
public partial class SuperButton : Button
{
    public SuperButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Brush MouseOverBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(MouseOverBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MouseOverBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOverBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(SuperButton));
}
```

SuperButton.xaml будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<Button x:Class="Example.SuperButton"
    x:Name="button"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>

                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="buttonSurface" Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}"/>
                        <Label x:Name="buttonCaption" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="buttonSurface" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding ElementName=button, Path=MouseOverBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="buttonCaption" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Теперь в триггере мы биндим цвет к свойству зависимости. Все.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <local:SuperButton MouseOverBrush="BlueViolet" Width="100" Height="50" />
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я видимо не объяснил, что я имею ввиду под словом "аналогично". Требуется НЕ объединить параметры цвета при наведенном курсоре и обычном режиме, а сделать второй атрибут, который можно указать при объявлении кнопки. Не залезая и редактируя сам стиль.

Comment: @Opossum, 1) Можно создать свой UserControl, в котором у Вас уже будет свойство отвечающее за цвета в триггерах. 2) Можно определить несколько различных кистей в стиле и, к примеру, в зависимости от свойства Tag кнопки использовать нужную кисть. 3) Использовать уже существующие свойства, которые не используются. Например в `BorderBrush` класть цвет, который вы хотите использовать для триггера.

Comment: Не пойму как конкретно нужно передавать параметры через binding из usercontrol'a. Как я понял нужно в xaml US написать (_Пример_) `Width="{Binding RadiusProperty}" Height="{Binding RadiusProperty}"`, а в cs файле контрола работать с этим радиусом через конструкцию propdp. Вот только не пойму, как это делать. Гугл не решил проблему.

Comment: @Opossum, Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще 2 вопроса. 1) Если в MainWindow.xaml (или где то еще) не задавать MouseOverBrush, то при наведении курсора на кнопку, она начинает моргать. Как это убрать? 2) Как установить значения по умолчанию для такого UserControl'a?

Comment: @Opossum, Она начинает моргать, потому что не указан цвет который устанавливается при наведении курсора. Чтобы задать цвет по умолчанию измените регистрацию свойства зависимости на `DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOverBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(SuperButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));`